# How to add class to dropdownlist using jquery depending on option

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to add css class dropdownliststyle to dropdown only when "please select" is selected on focus.how do i do that?

here is my jsfiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/3dj3srxp/ to that

CSS

```
 .DropDownStyle {
   background-color: red;
   color: white;
 }
```

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[type="text"]').each(function() {
      $(this).focus(function() {
        $(this).addClass('textBoxStyle');
      });

      $(this).blur(function() {
        $(this).removeClass('textBoxStyle');
      });
    });

    $('select').focus(function() {
        $(this).addClass('DropDownStyle');
    });

    $('select').blur(function() {
        $(this).removeClass('DropDownStyle');
      });

  });
```

Comment: See my updated answer...it would be better to use the 'change' function, and check the value... I have a update to your fiddle in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an if statement to check for the value, and it would actually be better to use the change function:

```
$('select').change(function() {
  if ($(this).val() == "select") {
    $(this).addClass('DropDownStyle');
  } else {
    $(this).removeClass('DropDownStyle');
  }
 });
```

You can see the fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/3dj3srxp/3/

Answer (score 4):

Let's do it in one line.

```
$('select').on('change', function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('DropDownStyle', $(this).val() == 'select');
});
```

Comment: wish i can mark more than one solution as answer. different way of doing it.good to know. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The focus applies only to input elements if you want to change the color of the select box maybe you will use the 'change' event:

```
$('select').on('change',function() {
   $(this).removeClass('DropDownStyle');

   if($(this).val() == 'select'){
     $(this).addClass('DropDownStyle');
   }
});
```

Comment: The reason for that is that kevindeleon has changed something in your HTML after I posted my answer. So I had to update my answer again. If you are doing this as validation I will advise you to check for the inserted values when the user submit the form and avoid posting the form if something goes wrong. Cheers :)